# pdo select latest from table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, content-management-system

I have this code to display from my Mysql database.

```
class cast {
public function fetch_all(){
    global $pdo;
      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM podcast limit 1");
      $query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
              }
```

this code does indeed display only 1 result as per the LIMIT 1 bit.

but this diaplays my 1st post.

my posts have a numeric ID under the name of cast_id

**How can I get the code above to display the latest addition (for example the highest number in cast_id) and not the first one?**

please help.

thank you.

Comment: [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: where do I add that fred?

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: Try changing `$query->fetchAll();` to `$query->lastInsertId();` but again, read the manual on the function to get familiar with it.

Comment: im dyslexic and can not read that page. I like to learn by examples not by gobuldigoop words.

Comment: Guess what, I'm dyslexic too (*yeah, really*) and I never let that stop me. Don't expect to go through life having people write code for you, you'll end up with some pretty nasty surprises when your potential future employer will quiz you on functions and debugging. You'll never "learn" anything that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like

```
class cast {
public function fetch_all(){
    global $pdo;
      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM podcast ORDER BY cast_id DESC LIMIT 1");
      $query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
              }
```

That should fetch the latest one.

Comment: this brings back NO results

Comment: @kevstarlive it is NOT supposed to bring any results, but to show you basic actions you HAD to learn yourself

Comment: @kevstarlive exactly what `@YourCommonSense` just said.

Comment: @dbh No that won't fetch the lastest that will trigger an MySQL error... limit 1 should behind the ORDER BY ... DESC

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for that, completely looked past it :/

Comment: hi dbh. i noticed how you changed this. i tryed it before you changed after reading Raymond Nijland's comment above and it works. thanks.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The OP is dyslexic. How do you expect the OP to understand any of that [gobuldigoop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467831/pdo-select-latest-from-table?noredirect=1#comment28870307_19467831) ? - I'm being sarcastic of course. (`+1`) on [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467831/pdo-select-latest-from-table?noredirect=1#comment28869845_19467874) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Please check http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

You need to return 
$pdo->lastInsertId(); after you execute the insert

Answer (score 1):

You can use order by clause like this :

```
class cast {
public function fetch_all(){
    global $pdo;
      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM podcast order by cast_id desc limit 1");
      $query->execute();
 return $query->fetchAll();
          }
```

Check the [SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are only right about the error but i didn't copy dbh. The next time check the time of answers and revision history before accusing people. I answered 10 seconds before dbh.

Comment: mine mistake i will remove the comment, and i don't know how to do that check the revision history i don't think i can see it..